# Execute specific cells in jupyter notebook before main one

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Say I have a main cell in my notebook, lets call in `main`. I don't want to run a whole bunch of cells each time I use main, but I have to because `main` depends on the functions in them.

Hence, if `main` depends on say cells `c1` and `c2` is there a special magic command or something one can place in `c1` and `c2`, that tells the notebook to run these before I run `main`. My notebooks typically contain hundreds of cells, so loading them all from the start is not really an option.

Thanks

PS. I am fully aware that I can take all of this out of notebooks and just import the whole lot. I specifically do not want to do that.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do this without extensions.

Have a look on [init_cell](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/init_cell/README.html) extension. It allows you to mark some cells and run them on load\demand.

Here is the [installation instructions](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).